# Error referencing segues UITextField's " !Use of unresolved identifier ‘segueTitleLine.text”

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I have a Swift - Single View app I am building.  I’ve added a “segue" view to allow user to store preferences using NSUserDefaults.  I would like the segue to be populated with the current preferences from their NSUserDefaults.  I think the place to do this is by overriding “prepareForSegue" but I can’t figure out how to reference the UITextfield’s in the segue without getting the error

> " !Use of unresolved identifier ‘segueTitleLine.text”

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //miscellaneous @IBOutlets here
    ..
    //override viewWillAppear and viewWillLoad here

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let titlePref = defaults.objectForKey("usertitleLineKey")!
        segueTitleLine.text = titlePref as? String     >>>>>>>  ERROR !Use of unresolved identifier ‘segueTitleLine.text
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is `segueTitleLine`? Where is it defined?

Comment: You need to get the `destinationViewController` property from the segue - this is the view controller that is about to be displayed.  set the properties using that

Comment: I am not sure how to get the properties or how to "set" them to get to the segue UITextField.    segueTitleLine is a UITextfield in the segue.